# How to fill a Rectangle (a Rect object) with an image in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I've tried this:

```
QBrush brush(QPixmap(":/new/prefix1/car.jpg"));
painter.setBrush(brush);
QRectF car(positions[i],120, 20, 10 );
painter.drawRect(car);
```

It shows the image but it repeats itself during a simulation in QPaint.
I want a way to fill a rectangle with an image but i'm not finding any specific methods for Rect. Any tricks for that?

Comment: Why don't you use [`drawPixmap()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#drawPixmap)? this will let you draw a pixmap into a `QRectF`. `drawRect` just draws a rectangle using the current brush, and since your brush's texture is set to the pixmap you want to draw, the pixmap will be repeated in the rectangle.

Comment: there are no specific methods for `QRectF`. After all, [`QRectF`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrectf.html#details) just defines a rectangle in the plain, it just consists of an upper-left corner and a size, it is usually used just to define the coordinates where drawing needs to happen on a specific paint device.

Answer (score 1):

Use QPainters `drawPixmap`. There is an overloaded function, that takes both a QPixmap and a QRect into which the pixmap will be painted:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#drawPixmap-9